# Calling C library from Rust gives "LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file"

Tags: c, rust, linker, ffi

I'm trying to call the STM32 Cube Programmer C libraries from Rust.

The entire code, and branches showing various attempts, are available here:
https://github.com/becky112358/rust_c_linking_stm32_cube_programmer

#### Attempt 1 (in my GitHub repository, branch `main`)

Following the Rust Bindgen tutorial: https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-bindgen/

This is my preferred method. A Rust crate wraps the C library.  Other Rust crates can then include the Rust wrapper crate, and not have to worry about any C libraries.

... in theory.

The Rust crate wrapping the C library (`libstm32_cube_programmer_sys`) builds ok. Its tests run ok.
The Rust crate calling the Rust crate which wraps the C library (`caller`) does not build, but reports:

```
    = note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '.\drivers\CubeProgrammer_API.lib'
```

Why is `caller` even trying to look for the C library? I expected `libstm32_cube_programmer_sys` to handle all C library to Rust conversion, and that any Rust crates then calling `libstm32_cube_programmer_sys` could be purely Rusty (with maybe some unsafeness).

- In `build.rs` I initially mis-wrote the C library name, and `libstm32_cube_programmer_sys` did not build. Correcting the library name allowed `libstm32_cube_programmer_sys` to build successfully. So it seems like `libstm32_cube_programmer_sys` does open the C library.
- I tried adding the path to the `drivers` folder to my `PATH`.
- I tried listing the absolute path to the C library:

```
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=C:/[blah blah]/drivers/CubeProgrammer_API");
```

I could not find how to feed in the path correctly, without Rust reporting:

```
    error: renaming of the library `C` was specified, however this crate contains no `#[link(...)]` attributes referencing this library.
```

#### Attempt 2 (branch `all_in_one`)

In the `main` branch it seemed like maybe the problem was that `libstm32_cube_programmer_sys` could find the C library but `caller` could not. So I tried discarding the separate Rust crate, and having a single Rust crate which both wraps the C library and calls the C functions.

This time I get the following error, plus a bonus warning:

```
    = note: caller.59pofysds2mkvvjr.rcgu.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol disconnect referenced in function _ZN6caller4main17ha79648c0a9e86ed0E
    .\drivers\CubeProgrammer_API.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
```

#### Attempt 3 (branch `link_search`)

I searched a lot on the internet and found lots of different ways to call a C library from Rust. One way is to use `link-search` rather than `link-lib`. This surely only makes things harder for the compiler because you make it do more work. But I am stuck and need to try different things!

This time I get the following error, plus the bonus warning:

```
    = note: caller.59pofysds2mkvvjr.rcgu.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_disconnect referenced in function _ZN6caller4main17ha79648c0a9e86ed0E
    .\drivers\CubeProgrammer_API.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
```

#### Question

How do I make this work? Ideally from *Attempt 1*, but I'll take anything!

Comment: Note that "cannot open input file" is the canonical example of a useless error message.  The mere existence of this question is evidence for that (if any evidence is needed!)  You *must* *always* provide a reason for the error in the error message.

Comment: Don't guess and say "make sure the file exists and you have permissions" or some other mumbo jumbo that might come out of a marketing department.  Give the reason. If your code is too complicated to find the value of errno when `open` was executed, refactor your code to make it doable.  Handling errors well is difficult.  Handling them poorly is a cop out.

Comment: Can you try solution 1, with an absolute path, but _without_ the `C:` part? I.e. your example would become: `println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=/[blah blah]/drivers/CubeProgrammer_API");`

Comment: I suspect that this will bring you to the same error as the other two, which comes from the fact that `CubeProgrammer_API.lib` is a 32-bit library and you're trying to build a 64-bit program.

Comment: @Jmb Then the Rust crate `libstm32_cube_programmer_sys` builds ok, but `caller` fails with the following:


  = note: LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/dev/sandpit/rust/rust_c_linking_stm32_cube_programmer/libstm32_cube_programmer_sys/drivers/CubeProgrammer_API.lib'; ignored


          caller.59pofysds2mkvvjr.rcgu.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol disconnect referenced in function _ZN6caller4main17ha79648c0a9e86ed0E

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Microsofts linker to answer that. You will have to look in its docs for the proper syntax for specifying a library (try `link /?`).

Comment: Or maybe the issue is with the forward slashes. Try replacing them with backslashes (remember to escape them): `println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=\\[blah blah]\\drivers\\CubeProgrammer_API");`

Comment: It works! Thank you @Jmb. It seems there were two problems:<br/>
1. The crate `caller` could not find the `.lib` library file. Ok, I realise that the warning already told me that. But I am confused. I thought that only the crate which wraps the C library would need to see it? For now my (hacky!!) solution is to place the `.lib` file in a symmetric location...<br/>
2. I need to use the x64 library, not the x86 library. Yes, I should have paid attention to the warnings and not just the errors!

Answer (score 1):

When we have:

C library <- Rust library <- Rust code

It seems that

- when compiling, the Rust code needs to be able to see the C library, even though it is also calling the Rust library
- when running, there may be C dlls which you need to store alongside the Rust exe

That was my main misunderstanding when I posted my original question.

Some other tips / reminders:

- Make sure to use the correct lib file! (x64, x86 etc)
- Resolve warnings too!